# jhbuild sanitycheck failing on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)

Tags: 14.04, xml, jhbuild

I'm trying to set up jhbuild on Ubuntu 14.04.  When I run `jhbuild sanitycheck`, I get two messages:

```
Could not find DocBook XML DTD V4.1.2 in XML Catalog
Could not find DocBook XSL Stylesheets in XML Catalog
```

The code that checks this in jhbuild is

```
for (item, name) in [('-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN',
                                  'DocBook XML DTD V4.1.2'),
                                 ('http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/html/chunk.xsl',
                                  'DocBook XSL Stylesheets')]:
                try:
                    data = get_output(['xmlcatalog', '/etc/xml/catalog', item])
                except:
                    print 'Could not find %s in XML catalog' % name
```

and, sure enough, in `/etc/xml/catlog`, there are entries which almost, but not exactly, match what the code is looking for. Eg. a reference to 
`-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML` (no version number) and 
`http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/` (without the `current/html/chunk.xsl` bit).

The official Ubuntu `docbook-xml` and `docbook-xsl` packages are installed.

It looks like the contents of `/etc/xml/catalog` aren't what `jhbuild` is expecting.  14.04 was installed from scratch; I've added a few other packages from various PPAs but can't think what could have changed this.

1. Anyone else experiencing this?  (I'll see if it's the same on a fresh install on a VM)
2. What's the best way of fixing it - should I edit `/etc/xml/catalog`, change the jhbuild sanitycheck source (but would any other part of the system then break) or something else?